# How about a Cookbook section of the meta site, or promote a "cookbook" tag?

Tags: feature-request

Over time, users have figured out various tricks for getting the most out of stack overflow.  Like writing screen scrapers, techniques and tools for using the rss feeds effectively, various browser add-ons, etc.  Sometimes they share their ideas and code here.  But you sort of have to get lucky to stumble on them, or spend a lot of time searching.  And I'm sure there are people out there who have set things up for themselves and not felt motivated to document it on meta.stackoverflow.com.

So initially I was thinking that it would be great if there was a "cookbook" section within meta specifically for this.  But I suppose people could just start using the tag "cookbook".  But to help it take off, you would want the stackoverflow developers to officially sanction/recommend it.  For example, mention it in the site faqs and encourage people to use it.  In fact I'd bet that users would take it as a challenge to try to create popular "recipes".

An added benefit would be that features needed by stack overflow would tend to rise to the top.

If it's not clear what kinds of topics I'm talking about, look at the some of the questions (in meta) tagged with screen-scraping, rss, greasemonkey, browser-enhancement, statistics, hidden-features.

Comment: +1 Good idea, although I'm not sure about calling it "cookbook"

Comment: Ah... I opened this suggestion hoping to find something about food. Now i'm disappointed. And hungry. Boo...

Comment: I guess it doesn't have to be "cookbook".  But I think that use of the term is pretty familiar to a lot of (most?) developers.  Maybe someone will have a better one.

Comment: I would be happy to support such an initiative.

Answer (score 2):

It's a community-driven site. If you go ahead and start a few community-wiki questions that feature interesting tricks for others to use, the rest of the community will either react positively or negatively. Use that response to gauge whether to continue.

Seriously, just give it a try. The worst that can happen is you'll get downvoted.

Comment: and if it's community wiki you won't feel the pain associated with the social stigma!

Comment: Good suggestion.  I was thinking it would build up faster if others who already worked on these tools got involved from the start.  But I shouldn't just assume it's a good idea.  Now I just need to work on some good recipes...